# What testing method can be used with demographic data to compensate for possible non-response bias?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, demography, non-response

(Hello CrossValidated, first poster here, so please have mercy with any transgressions of mine!)

For my thesis, I am currently researching the correlation between stance to organizational change and satisfaction with the managerial communication of said change.

For that purpose, I conducted an online survey before the implementation of the change initiative. Due to the small size of the population (N=130), I decided to do a census survey instead of choosing a random sample.

For that survey, I achieved a response rate of 57%. With a 95% confidence level, this would give me a margin of error of 7.38 which is well within the 12.5 I aimed for (the answers relevant for the correlation calculations are 5-point Likert scale, i.e. I am under the impression that a confidence interval of 25% is sufficient).

But afaik this calculation is only valid for random samples. Since I can not prove the non-responses are MAR, I have to assume non-response bias in my results. Due to data protection policies of the organization I am doing my research in, the survey was anonymous and hence I have no way of doing any follow up on the non-respondents (I am aware of). I do, however, have some demographic data on the population I also asked for in the survey, which gave me the following results (please excuse the poor formatting, I did not find a better way to draw tables):

```
Set 1
Branch    Population    Survey
1         42%           53%
2         44%           34%
3         14%           13%

Set 2
Location  Population    Survey
1         68%           66%
2         8%            10%
3         14%           14%
4         1%            1%
5         7%            8%
6         1%            0%

Set 3
Age       Population    Survey
1         0%            0%
2         12%           10%
3         42%           46%
4         28%           28%
5         17%           15%
6         1%            0%

Set 4
Seniority Population    Survey
1         31%           37%
2         39%           34%
3         23%           23%
4         7%            6%
5         0%            1%
```

My question now is:
What testing method - if any - can be used with this demographic data to gain an indication for the possible existence of non-response bias?
Or is it acceptable, given the demographic data in this case, to simply argue that the responses are sufficiently random to use the margin of error calculations for random samples?